blocked by CORS policy AWS 2 processes in one container python flask-cors
I have 2 processes running in 1 Docker container. A frontend and a backend. While the docker container is running properly in my computer, when deploying in aws ecs I get the following error:
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:5001/list-pdfs' from origin https:awsxxxxxxxxxxx has been blocked by CORS policy: The request client is not a secure context and the resource is in more-private address space local.
At the moment the CORS in my app.py looks like this
CORS(app, resources={r"/*": {"origins": "*"}})
app.config['CORS_HEADERS'] = 'Content-Type'
.
.
.
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5001, debug=True)

Has anyone else run in this issue and how you fixed that?
I have followed recomendations from other users without successrunning-into-issues-with-cors-with-flask
python-flask-cors-issue with no success.
I have tried Cors with and without specifing origin as well as reading in enviroment variable for the origin.

CORS errors are created by your browser, based on the CORS response they receive from a server.  It looks like your web browser is trying to hit a URL at localhost not a URL of a website running on ECS. If you have front-end javascript code that trying to make requests to localhost those requests will happen in the user's web browser which will then try to access something else running on the user's computer. The 2 processes aren't really running "in one container" the front-end is running in the browser, the container just serves the raw files for the frontend.

Hello Mark. Thank you very much for your comment. The frontend is in Angular, How would I solve this?

Change the angular code to use the IP address or the DNS name of the server.

See https://wicg.github.io/private-network-access/
